# ReadProcessMemory to memcpy conversion. Need help

Tags: memcpy

I'm using:

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(PVOID)(dwEngine_DLL+0x2E15C8+i),&memSnap[i],1,NULL); //Store the memory into a byte array
```

To store a section of memory into an array of byte, but I realized this was sloppy since I'm in the same address space, but I'm not sure how to do the same thing with memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I figured it out.

```
memcpy((void *)&memSnap[i],(PVOID)(dwEngine_DLL+0x2E15C8+i),1);
```

Pretty easy.